# struct table inside struct - ASP.NET - allegro webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, struct

I stopped in one point. I'm writing a small ASP.NET application with WebAPI from polish site allegro.pl (it's similiar to ebay.com)

This API have a method which returns me some data:

```
(...)
3. searchArray | SearchResponseType[]
Struct table, where are the information about offers that matches the question
(...)
```

Inside this struct there 28 types of data which are returned, for ex:

```
    1. sItId | long
       Offer id
    2. sItName | string
       Title of offer
     etc..
     (...)
```

And on the end there is a struct table with 2 subfields

```
     28. sItAttribsList | AttribStruct[]
          Struct table which contains informations about parameters assigned to offer

          1. attribName | string
             Name of parameter
          2. attribValues | string[]
             Table of parameter values
```

Okay - in my code behind I want to retrieve those information and display them on my page.

I have a model which contains fields like the fields which are returned from WebAPI

```
namespace allegrotest.Models
{
    public class SearchArrayModel
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        (...)
        public struct AttribStruct
        {
            public string AttribName { get; set; }
            public string[] AttribValues { get; set; }
        }
        public AttribStruct[] AttribStructTable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
foreach (SearchResponseType item in sercharray)
{
    SearchArrayModel searchArrMdl = new SearchArradyModel
    {
    ID = item.sitid,
    Name = item.sitname,
    (...)

    AttribStructTable = new SearchArrayModel.AttribStruct[]
    {
        //what now? Because I can't enter to the fields from my Model
    }
}
```

The problem is in the line

```
   AttribStructTable = new SearchArrayModel.AttribStruct[]
```

I don't know is it declared right or maybe I'm making something bad.
How to solve this?

Or maybe I have something wrong in my Model? Maybe AttribStructTable won't be a table? (If AttribStructTable isn't a table I can get to the fields, otherwise I can't)

Maybe - http://allegro.pl/webapi/documentation.php/show/id,116#method-output
It's the link with the information, it's in Polish, so you have to click "Dane zwracane" - it's "Returned data"

Comment: It is an array, not a table. What is the problem you have exactly?

Comment: The problem is - how to initialize AttribStructTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard array initialization. The only difference is that you have an array of structs.

Just use:

```
AttribStructTable = new [] 
{
   new AttribStruct 
   {
       AttribName = "YOUR_NAME",
       AttribValues = new [] { "Value1", "Value2" }
   },
   // There can be n array items
}
```

Reference to [MSDN arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [MSDN structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @karolinka if you don't mind please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm "fresh" user :)